# Can we pass either of two boolean variables to child component Like this

Tags: angular

I have a component for loading a spinner. How to load the component when either of the two booleans are true.

```
<custom-component [loading]="loading"></custom-component> 
<custom-component [loading]="loadClass"></custom-component>
```

Now, Can I make above code with one line something like this

```
<custom-component [loading]="loading || loadClass"></custom-component>
```

Comment: share your code as well plz.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, please show us what you've attempted.

Comment: are you using the loading property in you custom component using `@Input()` ?

Comment: yes you can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a function that will check for you. This could look like so.

This means you can easily add to the logic if the loading logic grows unlike the `||`.

```
<app-loading-spinner [loading]="isLoading()"></app-loading-spinner>
```

Then a simple function that checks and returns the value, this logic can be expanded over time.

```
public isLoading(): boolean
{
    if (this.loading || this.loadClass)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

> Now, Can I make above code with one line something like this

Yes that should work as it will check if one or the other is true and if so will pass in true, Otherwise it will pass in false.

You should be able to test thing by setting up an `@Input public loading: boolean` in your child component and checking its value.

Answer (score -1):

`*ngIf="cond1 && cond2"` should solve your problems.

Comment: he said either not both

Comment: *ngIf="cond1 || cond2"

Comment: @bogdanioan do not add a correct to your answer in a comment.  Edit the answer and fix it.